# atomic function is differentiable at at least one point.

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots$ be distinct reals in $(0,1)$.

Let $f:(0,1)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a function such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty f(a_n)$ converges and $f$ is $0$ at all points other than the $a_i$.

Prove that a point $x$ in $(0,1)$ exists such that $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

Clearly we must have $f(x)=0$. I have tried assuming no such $x$ exists but have gotten nowhere.

Comment: x is differentiable at x?

Comment: $f$ is of bounded variation, and so is differentiable a.e.

Comment: oh yeah that kills it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence of the series implies that $f$ is of bounded variation, and so is differentiable a.e.